# how to join two or more tables and result set having all distinct values

Tags: excel, ms-access, data-migration

I have some 20 excel files containing data. all the tables have same columns like id name age location etc..... each file has distinct data but i don't know if data in one file is again repeated in another file. so i want to join all the files and the result st should contain distinct values. please help me out with this problem as soon as possible. i want the result set to be stored in an access database.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend either linking the sheets in acces, or importing the sheets as tabels.

Then from there try to determine using a DISTINCT select from the tables/sheets the keys required, and only selecting the records as required.

Comment: thanks for your reply but what i am looking is i want all the data from two files without repetition. i mean 
 
 id name loc
 1  a     hi
 2  b     hu
 3  c     by

id  name  loc
1   d     xy
2   b     hu
3   h     bj


i want 

id  name  loc
1   a     hi
2   b     hu
3   c     by
4   d     xy
5   h     bj

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can use JOIN or NATURAL JOIN to join tables. I would look into NATURAL JOIN since you said all tables have the same values.

After that you can use DISTINCT to get distinct values.

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for though: your question asks about excel but you've tagged it with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use all the tables in one query, you can use a `union` to get the distinct rows:

```
select id, name, age, location from Table1
union
select id, name, age, location from Table2
union
select id, name, age, location from Table3
union
...
```

You can insert the records directly from the result:

```
insert into ResultTable
select id, name, age, location from Table1
union
....
```

If you only can select from one table at a time, you can skip the insert of rows that are already in the table:

```
insert into ResultTable
select t.id, t.name, t.age, t.location from Table1 as t
left join ResultTable as r on r.id = t.id
where r.id is null
```

(Assuming that id is a unique field identifying the record.)

Comment: Hi guys thanks for you support but this is what i am having problem with 

 i have 20 excel files. each file containing distinct data so if we do any operations on the table there is no problem. but if i try to do union with other table then it show like this

 id  name  location etc etc....
1    xyz    bhu 
1    abc    hud
2    bhk

Comment: thanks for your reply but what i am looking is i want all the data from two files without repetition. i mean 
id name loc
1 a hi 
2 b hu 
3 c by 

id name loc 
1 d xy 
2 b hu 
3 h bj 

i want 

id name loc 
1 a hi 
2 b hu 
3 c by 
4 d xy 
5 h bj

Comment: If I understand you right (after reading your comments several times), you should just omit the id from the Excel files altogether so that the records are distinct on rest of the data, and have a counter field in the Access database that creates new id:s for the records as you add them.

Comment: Guffas answer and comments will do what you need.  I would just add that I would import all the 20 excel sheets into access as 20 tables (not linked to the excel file) and go from there.  Also worth noting that if you use "UNION ALL" instead of UNION the repeated rows will be shown in your result set - which may be of use to you to inspect the data ( you might want to add an field to each select statement that provides the name of the sheet that the data is coming form  eg "Sheet A",

Answer (score 0):

It seems the unique set of data you want is this:

```
SELECT T1.name, T1.loc
  FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;DATABASE=C:\db1.xls;
       ].[Sheet1$] AS T1
UNION 
SELECT T1.name, T1.loc
  FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;DATABASE=C:\db2.xls;
       ].[Sheet1$] AS T1
```

...but that you then want to arbitrarily apply a sequence of integers as `id` (rather than using the id values from the Excel tables).

Because Access Database Engine does not support common table expressions and Excel does not support `VIEW`s, you will have to repeat that `UNION` query as derived tables (hopefully the optimizer will recognize the repeat?) e.g. using a correlated subquery to get the row number:

```
SELECT (
        SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
          FROM (
                SELECT T1.name, T1.loc
                  FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;DATABASE=C:\db1.xls;
                       ].[Sheet1$] AS T1
                UNION 
                SELECT T1.name, T1.loc
                  FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;DATABASE=C:\db2.xls;
                       ].[Sheet1$] AS T1
               ) AS DT1
         WHERE DT1.name < DT2.name
       ) AS id, 
       DT2.name, DT2.loc
  FROM (
        SELECT T2.name, T2.loc
          FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;DATABASE=C:\db1.xls;
               ].[Sheet1$] AS T2
        UNION 
        SELECT T2.name, T2.loc
          FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;DATABASE=C:\db2.xls;
               ].[Sheet1$] AS T2
       ) AS DT2;
```

Note:

> i want the result set to be stored in
>   an access database

Then maybe you should migrate the Excel data into a staging table in your Access database and do the data scrubbing from there. At least you could put that derived table into a `VIEW` :)

Comment: I think this answer is misleading.  The question implies that the WHOLE row might be in more than one file - including the ID.  Why does he need to apply new ID numbers!

Answer (score 0):

Join is to combine two tables by matching the values in corresponding columns. In result, you will get a merged table which consists of the first table, plus the matched rows copied from the second table. You can use [DIGBD](http://www.digdb.com) add-in for excel